# CIFS mountpoint timesout when attempting to Mount

Tags: fstab, cifs

I am trying to mount a folder in Windows (shared by Everyone)  to a centOS server using cifs. In `/etc/fstab`, I got:

`//192.168.x.x/DOUGSLAPTOP/hatest            /mnt/fsr01      cifs    guest    0 0`

I have also tried doing this:

```
//192.168.x.x/DOUGSLAPTOP/hatest            /mnt/fsr01      cifs    users,rw,user=Ryan,pass=Mon30 0 0
```

When I make this change, I get this for a response:

```
mount error(110): Connection timed out
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I don't think this is has to do with my firewall because I turned it off temporarily. Does anyone else have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way for non-user-name password is :

```
sec=none
```

Above configuration is mount option of `mount.cifs`

Comment: How do i apply this to mounting, I never used mount.cifs before..

Comment: You have to use `mount -t cifs -o sec=none //192.168.x.x/DOUGSLAPTOP/hatest /mnt/fsr01`

Comment: That didn't work. I updated my question

Comment: I think you add some optin to your mount please read man mount.cifs

Comment: I don't think this has to do with the problem, bus the mount.cifs manpage in Centos 7 states: """... While some versions of the cifs kernel module accept "user=" as an abbreviation for this option, its use can confuse the standard mount program into thinking that this is a non-superuser mount. It is therefore recommended to use the full "username=" option name. ..."""

Answer (score 1):

Providing option `guest` should make it not ask for a password, but it obviously won't work if a password is needed.

If a password is needed you can pass it as an option (`username=x,password=y`), or (better) pass a file with the credentials (username, domain, password) as an option (`credentials=/etc/cifs_mountpoint.cred`).

`man mount.cifs` for more details. You should also add `_netdev` as an option, and maybe `nofail` too.

Comment: the reason why i added guest was because I was taking a wild guess...I did this before successfully, i wish i remembered how i set this..